# How to arrange Linear Layout when visibility is set to Gone or Visible?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have a layout, I want to set Visibility Gone for any 2 items when I am setting visibility gone of Layout and floating action button then the floating action button is not arranging proper. Here is my xml file:

My design look like this

[image]

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#a62c23"
   >
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">


       <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#a62c23"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/viewA"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#a62c23"

                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:id="@+id/urintime"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Your In Time"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
                    />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/intimeshow"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
                        />
                    </LinearLayout>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="In Time"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#3645ab"
                    android:id="@+id/intime"

                    android:background="@drawable/buttonradius"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Out Time"
                    android:textColor="#3645ab"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/outime"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonradius"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:id="@+id/urouttime"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Your Out Time"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="current time"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/currenttime"
                    />
                    </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#dcba473e"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="#e6e3e3"
                    android:id="@+id/complaincount"
                    android:gravity="end|bottom"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Complains"
                    android:gravity="end|bottom"
                    android:textColor="#dad8d8"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/viewc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"


                android:background="#dcba473e"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"

                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:text="00"
                        android:textColor="#e6e3e3"
                        android:id="@+id/filecount"
                        android:gravity="end|bottom"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Files"
                        android:gravity="end|bottom"
                        android:textColor="#dad8d8"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"

                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/viewd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:background="#dcba473e"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:text="00"
                        android:textColor="#e6e3e3"
                        android:id="@+id/visitcount"
                        android:gravity="end|bottom"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Visit"
                        android:gravity="end|bottom"
                        android:textColor="#dad8d8"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/viewe"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:background="#dcba473e"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:text="00"
                        android:textColor="#e6e3e3"
                        android:id="@+id/ordercount"
                        android:gravity="end|bottom"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Order"
                        android:gravity="end|bottom"
                        android:textColor="#dad8d8"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="#ff6b7d"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:src="@drawable/complain"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            app:backgroundTint="#fbb570"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:fabSize="normal"

            android:src="@drawable/fileicon"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/viewB"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:backgroundTint="#5d9d83"
            android:src="@drawable/coms"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/viewc"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:backgroundTint="#4972a6"
            android:src="@drawable/iconorder"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/viewd"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/longitude1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cops"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/latitude1"
        />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried, `invisible` ?. This makes the respective view unseen, but with the view still taking it's space in the layout.

Comment: yup i tried it too.. but not working

Comment: if i set as invisible then the space is taking in the layout but i  don't want it

Comment: @DileepPatel: please desist from [useless edit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6768769/dileep-patel?tab=activity). Ideally, please describe what you changed, but if you cannot do that, leave it blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RelativeLayout` in `LinearLayout` and use invisible to hide .

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">
          </LinearLayout>
      </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout?
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set it to View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE

Comment: nope it is just invisible the layout but still space is taking i want to replace the view..

Comment: which view/layout do you want to sent to invisible ?

Comment: suppose i set visibility to Gone for ViewB(Linear Layout) & set visibility gone for floating action bar(fab) then the floating action bar is replace with space of View A

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html).

It gives you full control of what happens if a view in the middle "disappears".